# ODE solution approximation using Picard iteration, error approximation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems

On $I:=(0,\infty)$ let's consider the following Cauchy's problem:
$$y'=\frac{y}{2x^2}+1\qquad y(1)=0$$

a) Taking $\varphi_0:=0$ construct the first two Picard's approximations $\varphi_1,\;\varphi_2$

b) Let $\varphi$ be the exact solution to this problem. Using $\varphi_1,\;\varphi_2$ give an approximate value for $\varphi(\sqrt{2})$ and estimate the error of approximation.

So using the recursive Picard's method:
$$\varphi_{n+1}(x):= z + \int_{x_0}^x f\left(s,\varphi_{n}(s)\right)\;ds \qquad\text{where}\;\varphi_0(x)=z$$

In our case $f(x,y)=\frac{y}{2x^2}+1$ and if I didn't make any silly mistakes:
$$\varphi_1(x) = x-1$$
$$\varphi_2(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\log(x)+\frac{1}{x}+x-3\right)$$

I can approximate $\varphi(\sqrt{2})$ by computing $\varphi_2(\sqrt{2})$ but how can I evaluate the error ?

I found somewhere in my lecture that if we define the following application on a closed ball around $z$:
$$(T\phi)(x)=z+\int_{x_0}^x f(s,\phi(s))\;ds$$
We can show (under certain condition but it applies to my case) that $T$ is $L$-Lipschitz and so we have the following Lemma:
$$\forall p\geq 1:\quad\|(T^p\phi)(x)-(T^p\psi)(x)\|\leq\frac{1}{p!}L^p\cdot|x-x_0|^p\cdot\|\phi-\psi\|\qquad\text{Using}\;\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$$

But then I have to main issues. Firstly my upper limit of $L$ is: $L\leq\frac{b}{8}$ where $0<b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Then even if I assume I didn't make errors (which is clearly not clear) and continue on this road I arrive at the expression:
$$\|\varphi_2-\varphi\|_{\infty}\leq \frac{L^2}{2}\alpha^2\|\varphi\|\qquad(\alpha=\frac{1}{2})$$

So I cannot evaluate the error without knowing the maximum of the exact solution $\varphi$, so it is useless. I also tried to apply the fixed point theorem which state that:
$$\|x_\infty-x_n\|\leq\dfrac{c^n}{1-c}\|x_1-x_0\|\qquad\text{where $c$ is the contraction factor}$$
But totaly failed to find a way to make it work. I Googled ways to approximate the error on Picard's iteration but mostly found Master's level papers that are way above my level. Which path should I take to find this error ?

Comment: Is $T^p = T\circ \cdots \circ T$ ($p$-times)?

Comment: And isn't the last equality works? You just need to find out $c$: $x_0, x_1$ are found already.

Comment: Yes exactly, that's it. Yeah we have $x_0$ and $x_1$ but I cannot find $c$ in my case

Comment: To be exact, we only proved the formula at the end for function where $T$ is directly contractant ($L$-Lipschitz with $L<1$). But the upper bound of $L$ I found isn't always less than 1

Comment: Is $L$ the upper bound of $\left|\frac{\partial }{\partial y} f(t, y)\right|$?

Comment: We used earlier in the course: $L= \displaystyle\max_{i} \left\|\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right\|_\infty$. Using only the derivative with respect of $y$ give me an ok bound but with respect of $x$ is a higher value, so that's the $L$ I used

Comment: Thanks. I will try to write down an answer, basically just to bound $\varphi$. May I know the reference in proving the estimates involving $T^p$ using your $L$?

Comment: I do not have references as we work without a book but the context is the Picard-Lindelöf theorem and the specific formula can also be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#Optimization_of_the_solution's_interval)

Comment: I think I will just write down as a comment: from the differential equation, one can argue that $\varphi$ is positive and increasing. Since $x\ge 1$, we have $\varphi ' \le \frac{\varphi}{2} +1$. Integrating this gives $\|\varphi\| = \varphi (\sqrt 2) \le 2(\exp(\frac{\sqrt 2-1}{2})-1)$.

Comment: Ohhh I see, it seems to work thank you :)